# How to find "not a procedure" error

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x)(f (g x))))

(define (complement f) (cond ((equal? (comp f (lambda (g) g)) #t) #f)
                             ((equal? (comp f (lambda (g) g)) #f) #t)))

((complement odd?)2)
```

It keeps saying that ((complement odd?)2) is not a procedure. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Your implementation of `complement` is a mess. It really just need to compose `not` with the argument. Complement needs to return a procedure. I see the `cond` returning `#f`, `#t` and the undefined value when for the missing `else` clause and none of those are procedures and thus will provoke a "is not a procedure" when you try to apply the result.

Comment: How would I be able to fix it?

Comment: By changing `complement` from having a `cond` by just using `comp`. The complement of `(odd? x)` is `(not (odd? x))` and thus `((comp not odd?) x)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this code you'll see that `((complement odd?) 2)` is red in the definitions and you get the following error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
```

So that would mean `(complement odd?)` doesn't return a procedure but the value `#<void>`. Lets try that:

```
(complement odd?)
; ==> nothing (aka #<void>)
```

If you really want to see it use it somewhere:

```
(list (complement odd?))
; ==> (#<void>) now you see it
```

That means you are not handling all your possible checks in the `cond` in `complement` and I see why.. Have you tried `comp`?

```
(comp f (lambda (g) g)) ; ==> #<procedure>
```

Surely enough the use of `comp` becomes a procedure. Not strange since the  body has one lambda form that indicates the return would be a procedure. **It will never be `#t` or `#f`** When you don't have an `else` (default) term for when neither of your predicates became true `cond` returns an implementation specific defauls value. In Racket this is `#<void>` which is supressed by the REPL, but in other implementations it can be `banana` or whatever the implementers want it to be so you should always have a `else` clause. If you don't think you need it then do `(else (error "should never happen"))` and you're good to go. (try it)

The consequences in your `cond` are `#t` and `#f`. That means that if your code sould have worked you would have got this error message instead:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #t
```

For each place your return smething that is not a procedure that would be an error since you are using the result as a procedure. You need to change your implementation such that it returns a procedure always.

So, this is the answer to how to find “not a procedure” error. It's not the answer to how to fix your procedure but since this is the simplest procedure in the world I'll add it. You have a procedure `comp` that takes two procedures and return the composition of the two. eg. if you want add2 you can `(define add2 (comp add1 add1))`. The `complement` must be that the false value `#f` turns `#t` while all the true values turn `#f`. `not` does this so the composition of `not` and `odd?` would become the procedure that works the same as `even?`:

```
(define (complement f)
  (comp not f)) ; comp returns a procedure always

(define my-even? (complement odd?))
(my-even? 2) ; ==> #t
```

Since we don't mutate anything you can use substitution method to check what this does:

```
(my-even? 2)                      ; ==>
((comp not odd?) 2)               ; ==>
(((lambda (x) (not (odd? x))) 2)  ; ==>
(not (odd? 2))                    ; ==>
(not #f)                          ; ==>
#t
```